# How do you represent a function call as an if condition statement in Sequence Diagram?

Tags: c, uml, sequence-diagram

I've been drawing a sequence diagram of a module recently, while reverse engineering.
I encountered a control statement, and it is like,

```
if (func_A() == True)
{
    DoSomeThing();
}
else
{
    DoSomeThingElse();
}
```

The problem is how to draw the condition?

As I mentioned, It is reverse engineering. The code cannot be modified now.
I drew two diagrams, and I don't know which way is right,

The first one is this, I think it's wrong because it doesn't show the function call as a message from A to B.

[image]

This is the second, It shows a message func_A.

[image]

What do you think about to do this right?

Answer (score 4):

To complete the other answer there is anyway a problem in the second proposal because we do not know if in *[func_A() == True]* you reuse the value return by the previous call or you do a second call, to avoid that add the explicit return in your diagram :

[image]

---

Out of that do you know the activities ? A sequence diagram is "just" an interaction while an activity is a behavior and can be more adapted :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I think it would be more proper to draw a flow chart(or activity?) as well. However, in some reason, I'm doing it with sequence diagram.
I'll try flow chart next time.

Comment: +1. Thanks to the named response it is much more clear regarding the condition. It is also important to stress the better use of the execution occurrence since the whole process is depicted with a single execution occurrence on `Object1`.

Comment: I also was uneasy about the return result. But this one got me :-) [why that "Don't comment on your upvote.". Silly SO]. So: upvoted

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If `func_A` is an operation defined in `Object2` the second representation would be correct. The first does not tell where the operation is defined. Most likely (!) one would interpret `func_A` as an operation local to `ObjectA` which your code seems to say. (Btw. you have two completely different object sets AB vs. 12 in your examples.) But that is uncertain. So the 2nd variant is more explicit (and correct).

In any case I advise to not overdo SDs with fragments as "graphical programming" doesn't make things easier to read (my practical experience). It's excellent to show message flows in various collaborations. But when it comes to conditions it's getting messy very soon. A better way is to create different sub-diagrams or even use pseudo code if there are too nested if conditions. In many cases such if clauses are a good fit for state machines.

Comment: +1 In my projects I always use diagrams to replace the proverbial thousand words. They should make things clear, not obfuscated.